# Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication start method

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish

i'm trying to start-up a job scheduler upon application deployment. I'm using quartz api with all required jar  files included but i'm getting `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`. here is the server log message for the exception:

```
SEVERE:   Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication start method
javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.CreateException: Initialization failed for Singleton Cam2JobSchedular
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer$SingletonContextFactory.create(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:656)
    at....more

Caused by: java.lang.Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackInvocationContext.proceed(CallbackInvocationContext.java:209)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:986)....
```

here is the simple code i'm trying to run upon deployment of my application:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class Cam2JobSchedular 
{

    private static final Logger logger=Logger.getLogger(Cam2JobSchedular.class.getName());

    @PostConstruct  
    public void init() {
        //start the trigger
       try
       {
         JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(Cam2UpdateCentralDBJob.class)
                    .withIdentity("UpdateCam2Data").build();
            // specify the running period of the job

            Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
                    .withSchedule(SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule()
                    .withIntervalInSeconds(30)
                    .repeatForever()).build();

            //schedule the job

            SchedulerFactory schFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
            Scheduler sch = schFactory.getScheduler();
            sch.start();
            sch.scheduleJob(job, trigger);

            logger.info("New Job started, Job ID: "+job.getKey().getGroup());
       }
       catch(Exception ex){}
    }
}
```

thanks i will appreciate your help guys

Answer (score 0):

You need to download [SLF4J](http://slf4j.org/download.html) and put the latest jar file onto your class path